# Where I can get the datasets containing article with its summarization?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp, news

I am trying to create a summarizer as my project and using ANN and AI for trying to get a dataset for the training purpose.

Kindly, suggest me where I can get a large dataset for training such a model? I am looking for unpaid datasets, ready to donate.

Kindly, help me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the type of API/data source you're looking for is precisely what the [New York Times API](https://developer.nytimes.com) serves up. While the API call you make can have any customization you wish, if you're looking for articles with summaries, author, timestamp and other metadata, you may want to go with their [Times Newswire API](https://developer.nytimes.com/timeswire_v3.json) or their [Top Stories](https://developer.nytimes.com/top_stories_v2.json) API.

Comment: Not exactly.. I am looking for original article and the summarized article so that I can train my models.

Comment: @JafferWilson The Top Stories API and Times Newswire include links to articles. The Article Search API includes abstracts. Maybe also specify how large you need the dataset to be.

Comment: @JafferWilson Could arxiv.org be what you're looking for. It's a pre-print server. You get metadata including the abstract as text an the original article (pre-print version) as PDF.